# Random slope for time in subject not working in lme4

Tags: r, missing-data, lme4

I can not insert a random slope in this model with lme4(1.1-7):

```
> difJS<-lmer(JS~Tempo+(Tempo|id),dat,na.action=na.omit)
Error: number of observations (=274) <= number of random effects (=278) for term 
(Tempo | id); the random-effects parameters and the residual variance (or scale
parameter) are probably unidentifiable
```

With nlme it is working:

```
    > JSprova<-lme(JS~Tempo,random=~1+Tempo|id,data=dat,na.action=na.omit)
    > summary(JSprova)
Linear mixed-effects model fit by REML Data: dat
AIC      BIC    logLik
769.6847 791.3196 -378.8424

Random effects:
Formula: ~1 + Tempo | id
Structure: General positive-definite, Log-Cholesky parametrization
            StdDev    Corr
(Intercept) 1.1981593 (Intr)
Tempo       0.5409468 -0.692
Residual    0.5597984       

Fixed effects: JS ~ Tempo 
                Value  Std.Error  DF   t-value p-value
(Intercept)  4.116867 0.14789184 138 27.837013  0.0000
Tempo       -0.207240 0.08227474 134 -2.518874  0.0129
Correlation: 
      (Intr)
Tempo -0.837

Standardized Within-Group Residuals:
        Min          Q1         Med          Q3         Max 
-2.79269550 -0.39879115  0.09688881  0.41525770  2.32111142

Number of Observations: 274
Number of Groups: 139
```

I think it is a problem of missing data as I have few cases where there is a missing data in time two of the DV but with `na.action=na.omit` should not the two package behave in the same way?

Comment: What version of `lme4` are you using? Does the following run: `sleepstudy$Reaction[1:10] <- NA ;(fm1 <- lmer(Reaction ~ Days + (Days | Subject), sleepstudy))`

Comment: Yes, it is working. I added the version of lme4 in the post.

Comment: Once I understand the problem, I have found very useful this discussion: [Mixed model with one observation per level] (http://stats.stackexchange.com/q/65371/58940).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is "working" with `lme`, but I'm 99% sure that your random slopes are indeed confounded with the residual variation.  The problem is that you only have two measurements per subject (or only one measurement per subject in 4 cases -- but that's not important here), so that a random slope plus a random intercept for every individual gives one random effect for every observation.

If you try `intervals()` on your `lme` fit, it will give you an error saying that the variance-covariance matrix is unidentifiable.

You can force `lmer` to do it by disabling some of the identifiability checks (see below).

```
library("lme4")
library("nlme")
library("plyr")
```

Restrict the data to only two points per individual:

```
sleepstudy0 <- ddply(sleepstudy,"Subject",
      function(x) x[1:2,])
m1 <- lme(Reaction~Days,random=~Days|Subject,data=sleepstudy0)
intervals(m1)
## Error ... cannot get confidence intervals on var-cov components

lmer(Reaction~Days+(Days|Subject),data=sleepstudy0)
## error
```

If you want you can force `lmer` to fit this model:

```
m2B <- lmer(Reaction~Days+(Days|Subject),data=sleepstudy0,
        control=lmerControl(check.nobs.vs.nRE="ignore"))
## warning messages
```

The estimated variances are different from those estimated by `lme`, but that's not surprising since some of the parameters are jointly unidentifiable.

If you're only interested in inference on the fixed effects, it *might* be OK to ignore these problems, but I wouldn't recommend it.

The sensible thing to do is to recognize that the variation among slopes is unidentifiable; there *may* be among-individual variation among slopes, but you just can't estimate it with this model. Don't try; fit a random-intercept model and let the implicit/default random error term take care of the variation among slopes.

There's a [recent related question on CrossValidated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/120650/one-observation-per-level-in-mixed-effect-model/120655#120655); there I also refer to [another example](http://ms.mcmaster.ca/~bolker/classes/uqam/mixedlab1.pdf).

Comment: Thanks Ben, now I understand the point. But what it is better to do now? It seems to me that it is not useful to use a more elaborated model with unreliable estimates. Should I use a random intercept model? For what I can understand this is a big limit as the variation in time can, and likely is different from subject to subject. Isn't this true?