# Fitting random factors for a linear model using lme4

Tags: r, lme4

I have 4 random factors and I want to provide its linear model using lme4. But struggled to fit the model.

Assuming A is nested within B (2 levels), which in turn nested within each of xx preceptors (P). All responded to xx Ms (M).

I want to fit my model to get variances for each factor and their interactions.

I have used the following codes to fit the model, but I was unsuccessful.

```
lme4::lmer(value ~ A  + 
      (1 + A|B) + 
      (1 + P|A), 
      (1+ P|M),
    data = myData, na.action = na.exclude)
```

I also read interesting materials [here](https://bbolker.github.io/mixedmodels-misc/glmmFAQ.html#nested-or-crossed), but Still, I struggle to fit the model. Any help?

Comment: "nested" means a lot of things.  Can you please expand your description of the experimental design?  It might help if you tell us what the A, B, M, P represent in the real world -- that often helps with interpretation (e.g. if A is "sex" and B is "people" we usually know that each B will experience exactly one value of A during the duration of the experiment ...)

Comment: (1) Can you please edit your question to include the info in your comment?  (2) just checking that participants are really nested within occasion - that means every participant was involved in one teacher/occasion combination?

Answer (score 1):

At a guess, if the nesting structure is ( `P (teachers) / B (occasions) / A (participants) )`, meaning that the occasions for one teacher are assumed to be completely independent of the occasions for any other teacher, and that participants in turn are never shared across occasions or teachers, but questions (M) are shared across all teachers and occasions and participants:

```
value ~ 1  + (1| P / B / A) + (1|M)
```

Some potential issues:

- as you hint in the comments, it may not be practical to fit random effects for factors with small numbers of levels (say, < 5); this is likely to lead to the dreaded "singular model" message (see the GLMM FAQ for more detail).
- if all of the questions (`M`) are answered by every participant, then *in principle* it's possible to fit a model that takes account of the among-question correlation within participants: the maximal model would be `~ 1 + (M | P / B / A)` (which would look for among-question correlations at the level of teacher, occasion within teacher, and participant within occasion within teacher).  However, this is very unlikely to work in practice (especially if each participant answers each question only once, in which case the teacher:occasion:participant:question variance will be confounded with the residual variance in a linear model). In this case, you will get an error about "probably unidentifiable": see e.g. [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26465215/random-slope-for-time-in-subject-not-working-in-lme4) for more explanation/detail.

Comment: Error: number of observations (=9) <= number of random effects (=9) for term (M | A:(B:P)); the random-effects parameters and the residual variance (or scale parameter) are probably unidentifiable
>

Comment: Why we do not get such error using SPSS? Very confusing!